# EnterpriseLibrary CacheManager Gone After Application Restart?

Tags: c#, wpf, caching, enterprise-library

I've got a C# WPF application.  I recently discovered the Microsoft Enterprise Library Caching options.

I added the following code to my application:

```
ICacheManager oCacheManager = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager();
if (!oCacheManager.Contains("TESTING"))
{
    //
    // Code which populates myDictionary object
    //

    oCacheManager.Add("TESTING", myDictionary);

    if (oCacheManager.Contains("TESTING")) 
        Console.WriteLine("Stored!");
}
else  // below never gets hit
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found It!");
    CachedObjects = (Dictionary<string, object>)oCacheManager.GetData("TESTING");
}
```

Every time the application is run, it outputs "Stored!".  It never outputs "Found It!".  This implies the cache is getting thrown out every time the application closes.  Is there a way to persist it so that each subsequent time it's started it finds the cache and loads it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default storage for cached objects is the NullBackingStore, which really means that the object is cached in memory only. The other options are IsolatedStorageBackingStore (written to disk in the user's isolated storage) and DatabaseBackingStore (written to a database). Both of these will be much slower than the NullBackingStore, but the data will remain after a restart.

Comment: Thanks.  I got it now.  Although Isolated Storage basically tells me my object is too large ("The internal array cannot expand to greater than Int32.MaxValue elements"), and database storage would mean going across the network, defeating the purpose of the cache.  So, I guess it won't work out.  Thanks for the help!